# Rails functional testing without migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, functional-testing

The name pretty much says it all. Does anyone know how to accomplish functional testing when you are not using migrations in Rails? I'd be open to any advice or third party libraries (if there are any). I thought of creating my own plugin to address this but it seems like a pretty big task and would rather not do this unless necessary.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that there is no "easy" way to do this. I'm looking into RSpec rails to see if it can be modified to not use migrations.

Answer (score 0):

http://github.com/jpignata/temping

> Temping allows you to create arbitrary ActiveRecord models backed by a temporary SQL table for use in tests.